# Rails obscure ActiveRecord UnknownAttribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When running the below in my Rails app, I'm getting an Unknown Attribute error.

```
@appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])

@appointment.update_attributes(appointment_params)
```

I'm getting a `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError`.  The unknown attribute is `appointment_id` on the Appointment model.

I've removed this field, removed the association on the model.rb, removed it from the strong params definition, and everywhere else I can think of.

I am not POSTing/PUTing the `appointment_id` to the server when creating or updating and I've verified this by returning `appointment_params` and it still does not come back.

What could be causing this error to be thrown?

Comment: Show this method `appointment_params` and the console log file output to show the error.......

Comment: params.require(:appointment).permit(:field1, :field2, :etc)

Comment: No.. show me the actual file.. if you didn't white-list this param.. it should not come.. and also console log to show the error...........

Comment: I have `appointment_id` in my strong params list, but it's in a nested attributes definition.  Other than that it's just fields.  Console log what?  This is Rails, not javascript.

Comment: I know this is Rails, that's why I opened your question here. Are you aware of `developement.log`.. `production.log`.. `test.log` files.. which are inside the `log/` directory...? When you do `rails s`, in developement mode.. what you see in your terminal is the content of `development.log` file.......

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment,

```
def appointment_params
  params.require(:appointment).permit(:field1, :field2, :etc) 
end
```

`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError` means that `:field1`, `:field2` or `:etc` are not in your database.

If you look at your schema.rb file, at least one of those fields should be missing from the `appointments` table.

FWIW, after you do Rails for 8 hours a day for a few years, this error will no longer be obscure.

Comment: That's not the problem.

Comment: Can you add the table from the schema.rb?

Comment: It says specifically, "unknown attribute: appointment_id" when this is the data I'm sending in the PUT request: `{"appointment":{"appointment_hierarchies_attributes":[{"parent_id":"1848","child_id":"159"}]}}`